# iPod Device not recognized in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5, ipod

I have an ipod touch newly upgraded to `IOS 6.1`. In my `xcode(4.5.2)`, the device is not getting recognised. This happened just after I upgraded the device OS. I have tried restarting/rebooting device and restarting xcode and mac. But, still it is not recognised.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your Xcode to 4.6 to use iOS 6.1.